# Powershell: passing variable with program's full path and argument to ScriptBlock

Tags: powershell

I know there are other questions here on Stackoverflow regarding this topic, but none of them resolved my case. I have a full path to a given program, examples might be:

- C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Lorem\program1.exe
- C:\"Program Files"\Ipsum\program2.exe

If I try to execute it directly on the terminal via `C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Lorem\program1.exe /S` it will run with no issues, but if I try using my script it won't work:

```
# $full_path contains the string for the path, e.g. C:\"Program Files (x86)"\supersoftware\uninst.exe

Write-Host $full_path  # Will print on the screen: C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Lorem\uninst.exe
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock { cmd /c $full_path '"/S"' }  # /S is used for silent uninstall
```

How can I make PS execute it as if I were there on the terminal typing `C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Lorem\uninst.exe /S` and hitting enter?

Comment: When using a pathname that contains spaces, you quote the entire pathname, not just the portion that has spaces. Thus, your program should be referenced as `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Lorem\Program1.exe"`, not `C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Lorem\Program1.exe`

Comment: Ok, I'm passing it as `"C:\..."` with quotes outside and not inside. Now I'm getting a new error: `'/S' not recognized as an internal or external command`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the script block is invoked in a different session the variable will not exist by default.  You can use the `using` scope modifier to get around this.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName ServerName -ScriptBlock { cmd /c $using:full_path /S }
```

Note that the object will be serialized for remoting.  This won't effect a string, but complex objects will typically only contain the original property values.

Comment: `Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock { Start-Process -FilePath "$($using:full_path)" -ArgumentList "/s" }`

Comment: If it instantly finished running there is a good chance it didn't wait for the process to finish.  If the session closes before the process finishes the process will be terminated.  Try something like `Start-Process -FilePath $using:full_path -ArgumentList '/S' -Wait`.

Comment: It worked with `Invoke-Command -ComputerName ServerName -ScriptBlock { cmd /c $using:full_path /S }`, I was checking the wrong place!!!